# Execute Vim command in terminal window and return to Terminal-Job mode

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface, terminal-buffer

For a while, I'd been using `:nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h` and `:tnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h`, et. al. to switch windows. This was working great, so when I started using tabs, I decided to expand this mapping to also switch tabs when I reached the edge of the screen. To do that, I wrote the following:

```
function! WinTabSwitch(direction)
    let info = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]
    if a:direction == 'h' && info.wincol <= 1
        execute 'tabprev|99wincmd l'
    elseif a:direction == 'l' && info.wincol + info.width >= &columns
        execute 'tabnext|99wincmd h'
    else
        execute 'wincmd '.a:direction
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-H> :call WinTabSwitch('h')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-J> :call WinTabSwitch('j')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-K> :call WinTabSwitch('k')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-L> :call WinTabSwitch('l')<CR>
```

This works great, except when I'm trying to leave a terminal window. To fix that, I use these mappings,

```
tnoremap <silent> <C-H> <C-W>N:call WinTabSwitch('h')<CR>
tnoremap <silent> <C-J> <C-W>N:call WinTabSwitch('j')<CR>
tnoremap <silent> <C-K> <C-W>N:call WinTabSwitch('k')<CR>
tnoremap <silent> <C-L> <C-W>N:call WinTabSwitch('l')<CR>
```

but the unfortunate side effect is that the terminal window is left in **Terminal-Normal** mode. Is there a way to either

1. return to **Terminal-Job** mode after leaving the terminal window (After reading `:h Terminal-Normal`, I have my doubts.), or
2. call the function without leaving **Terminal-Job** mode?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure—use `<C-w>:` in your terminal mappings to get a colon command line instead of "escaping" to normal mode:

```
tnoremap <silent> <C-H> <C-W>:call WinTabSwitch('h')<CR>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: saved my day, thanks